# Flutter : Function need to wait

Tags: multithreading, flutter, dart, asynchronous

Here is my code

```
  Future<List<Record>> getRecordElements() async {
    int i=0;
    String at;
    var cont =0;
    List<String> name= [];
    var db = await FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("Volunteers/"+widget.vname+"/Records");
      db.once().then((DataSnapshot snapshot){
        Map<dynamic, dynamic> values = snapshot.value;
        print(values);
        values.forEach((key,values) async {
          if(values["cont"]!=null){
              //Few complicated operations 
              values.forEach((key,values) {
              print(values);
              if(key=="name"){
                name.add(values);
              }
              
            });
        });
      });
   

    print("name " + name.toString());
     
     //few more operations
      return items;
    }
```

I have modified out irrelevent parts of the code.

Thing is, `name` is an array whose values are fetched from the database. Only after the array is set, can function proceed.

But what is happening is that `name` is being printed before it has been set. And hence the other operations after that are also being affected.

I need the fetching to finish first, and only then move ahead.

Please help

Comment: In addition to the `.forEach` problem (and it's unclear why you've marked its callback as `async` when it doesn't seem to do any asynchronous work, unless that part was omitted), you neglect to `await` the result of `db.once().then()` (and calling `.then` then would be unnecessary anyway).

Answer (score 1):

I think You Should fetch Your data at initializing stage i.e. you should create a function to fetch data from database and then call that function from initState